# Estoy haciendo una app de practica en android studio utilizando retrofit y spring boot para el backend, pero no me carga ninguna petición

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, kotlin, retrofit

Esta es la clase para instanciar mi retrofit:

```
class RetrofitInstance {

fun getInstance(): Retrofit{
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.16:8080/")
        .client(httpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

}
```

Aca defino el Api service con las funciones que interactuan con las distintas urls

```
interface APIService {

@POST(value = "products/")
fun addProduct(@Body data : SaveProductRequest): Call<AddProductResponse>

}
```

Asi se esta el request:

```
data class SaveProductRequest(
var name: String
)
```

Y el response:

```
data class AddProductResponse(
@SerializedName("name")
val nameProduct: String
)
```

Ahora en mi main activity que es donde esta la interfaz para agregar un nuevo producto llamo a esta función desde el listener de un boton (uso la dependencia de Anko para ejecutar estas operaciones en background):

```
private fun addProduct(){
    val nameProduct = mainActivityBinding.editTextNameProduct.text.toString()

    if (nameProduct.isNotEmpty()) {
        mainActivityBinding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mainActivityBinding.btnSubmit.isEnabled = false
        doAsync {
            val dataProductRequest = SaveProductRequest(nameProduct)
            val call = RetrofitInstance().getInstance().create(APIService::class.java)
                .addProduct(dataProductRequest)
                .execute()
            uiThread {
                if (call.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Pedido exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    startActivity(Intent(it, ProductsListActivity::class.java))
                }
                else Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mainActivityBinding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                mainActivityBinding.btnSubmit.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

A continuación les mostrare mi backend, esta es la parte donde construyo las funciones que interactuan con la base de datos, por ahora solo hice la de agregar un producto:

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "/products")
 public class ProductsREST {

@Autowired
private ProductDao productDao;


@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(
        @RequestBody
        Product product
        ){
    Product newProduct = productDao.save(product);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(newProduct);
}

}
```

se que es bastante codigo pero agradeceria si alguien sabe porque cuando le doy al boton de agregado no me ejecuta correctamente la petición http de mi api rest, se que la logica del retrofit esta correcta porque probe con una url creada con beeceptor con los mismos parametros de entrada y salida y me lo ejecuto correctamente y por parte del backend usando postman probe la url y efectivamente me guarda el producto.

No se si la url deba declararse de forma distinta o que deberia hacer, GRACIAS de antemano.

Si necesitan alguna otra parte del proyecto en especifico se las suministrare, ya que obvie algunos fragmentos que no tienen tanta importancia a mi consideración.

Comment: cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Ese es el problema no me sale ningun mensaje de error, si ves en el codigo escrito en kotlin para hacer la petición de forma asincrona pongo visible un progress bar mientras carga y luego lo quito una vez termina la petición, pero cuando hago esto se queda cargando infinitamente sin darme una respuesta.

Comment: Por otra parte probe lo mismo pero usando Volley para ver si el problema estaba con retrofit que no me reconocia la petición y haciendo esta prueba con volley me mando un mensaje de error diciendo com.android.volley.ClientError

Comment: Agregaste el atributo `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` en tu manifest?

Comment: :DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD Era por eso, se me habia olvidado que android bloquea todas las peticiones http si el host no es seguro, iba a subir mi api rest a heroku, menos mal me acordaste, gracias